# Grand canonical ensemble $d\ln(\mathcal{Z})$

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Let us consider the grand canonical ensemble. Where here we have the grand partition function:
$$\mathcal{Z}=\text{tr}(e^{\beta(\mu N -H)})$$
Where $\mu$ is the chemical potential and $\beta =\dfrac{1}{kT}$.

I am reading some calculations, and am unsure how a step was completed:
$$d\text{ln}(\mathcal{Z})=\mathcal{Z}^{-1}d\mathcal{Z}=\mathcal{Z}^{-1}d\text{tr}(\text{tr}(e^{\beta(\mu N -H)}))$$
Which apparently equals:
$$(\mu \bar{N}-\bar{E})d\beta+\beta\bar{N}d\mu.$$
How is this so?

Comment: $\mathcal{Z}(\beta,\mu)$ can be regarder as a function of $\beta$ and $\mu$. Just make $d\ln\mathcal{Z}$ over these variables. BTW $\bar{X} = \text{Tr}(X e^{\beta(\mu N-H)})$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you wrote, but here's my answer.
If $\cal{Z}$ is the classical GC partition function, then it is defined as
$${\cal{Z}}=\sum_i e^{\beta(\mu N_i - H_i)}\equiv tr(e^{\beta(\mu N - H)})$$
where the sum if over the microstates of the system. Thus, since in principle $\mu=\mu(\beta)$, the derivative with respect to $\beta$ of its logarithm:
$$\frac{d}{d\beta}\ln{\cal{Z}}=\frac{1}{\cal{Z}}\frac{d}{d\beta}{\cal{Z}}$$
which is just a property of logarithms. Therefore
$$\frac{1}{\cal{Z}}\frac{d}{d\beta}\sum_i e^{\beta(\mu N_i - H_i)}= \frac{1}{\cal{Z}}\sum_i \big(\mu N_i - H_i + \beta N_i \frac{d\mu}{d\beta}\big)e^{\beta(\mu N_i - H_i)}=\mu\langle N \rangle - \langle H\rangle + \beta\langle N\rangle \frac{d\mu}{d\beta}$$
where the last equality comes from the definition of the expected value in the GC ensemble:
$$\langle A\rangle_{GC}=\frac{1}{\cal{Z}}\sum_i A_i e^{\beta(\mu N_i - H_i)}$$

Hope it helps!